# Module that will display 10 random featured articles with full read more text

Tags: module, articles, category

Ive spent quite a few hours looking but have been unable to find so far, but am thinking this must surely be available.

I just need a Joomla Module that will display random featured articles from a category. Perhaps 10 articles with full read more text without stripping any tags.

Thats it, surely Ive overlooked something obvious here!?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read more text could be either Read more... or the Read more with the title of the article...  What exactly you mean with full read more text without stripping any tags?

Answer (score 1):

Read more text could be either Read more... or the Read more with the title of the article...

What exactly you mean with full read more text without stripping any tags?

As for modules to show articles there are dozens in JED with so many features...

One I like it a lot and use it wherever it fits, it is [**Raxo all mode**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/raxo-all-mode-pro) (it's paid download though, but well worth its price). It provides many many options for what articles to show and how to show them.

Many filters like date, author, featured, popular, newest, tags and similarly many ordering options, including random selection.